# Launch App on connected Device without Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, xcode, developer-program

In the WWDC 2015 Keynote, Apple said that with the arrival of XCode 7 and Swift 2 **it will no longer be necessary to pay the Apple Developer Program suscription** to run our own iOS apps on our own connected devices.

What do I need to make use of this new feature?

Comment: I'm curious about this too... Could big boost to the open source iOS community, so long as everyone can compile for their own devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need:

- a Mac running Xcode 7 (which is currently in beta and not finished yet)
- an iOS device running iOS 9 (which is also in beta and not released yet) or iOS 8
- an Apple ID to sign into both Xcode and the iOS device - this will generate the provisioning profiles needed for your code to run on your devices.

To get prepared for this, download the [beta version of Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and follow one of the iOS session videos that show how to run one of the Apple-provided sample projects. You will then build and run that to your connected device as a target.

Eventually, the [latest Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) from the Mac App Store will have these features for anyone to use released versions of the tools on released iOS versions.

Comment: Also - is someone has questions on what specifically to do in Xcode or has  errors with a specific combination of OS X, Xcode, iOS - please ask a new question. Explaining everything in one answer would be quite long and broad.